# Hide and show logo based on user role

Tags: 7, theming, media

Drupal 7

Is it possible to write an if statement in the page.tpl.php file that first gets the user role and then compares it to a string and it either shows the logo or doesn't. Something like...

```
//some how get user role

global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);

$current_role = $user_fields->role[];

if ($current_role == "public_user"){
>?
<?php
 print $front_page; 
?>" title="

<?php
 print t('Home'); 
?>
" rel="nofollow">

?>
}else{
//don't show.
}
```

Comment: hook_page_alter()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest checking against a permission, rather than an entire role.

In your custom module, add:

```
function mymodule_permission() {
    return array(
        'view site logo' => array(
            'title' => t('View Site Logo'), 
            'description' => t('Allows a user to view the site logo'),
        ),
    );
}
```

And in your theme's template.php page preprocessor, add:

```
if(!user_access("view site logo")) {
    $variables['logo'] = "";
}
```

This way, $logo will not be processed in page.tpl.php for a user without the permission.

Comment: Thanks +1 stupid question... the custom module, is that something I create and upload via the module form?

Comment: Customizations can be made at many levels in Drupal. Typically users start at the theme layer with custom code/over rides in template.php of their site theme. For more advanced customizations a user can create a custom module from scratch and install it on their site. In "Jukebox" example above, the mymodule_permission function would be in your custom module and named after the module rather than "mymodule_permission" it could be "any_name_you_choose_permission".

Comment: Take a look at this: Create your first simple Drupal 7 module -> http://reinholdweber.com/2010/06/28/create-your-first-simple-drupal-7-module/

Answer (score 1):

Get the ROLE ID from the listing of roles in the admin section of site at http://YOURSITE.COM/node#overlay=admin/people/permissions/roles

```
global $user;

if (array_key_exists('ROLE ID', $user->roles)) {
  print $front_page; 
}
elseif (array_key_exists('SOME OTHER ROLE ID', $user->roles)) {
  print t('Home');
} 
else {
  //don't show.
}
```

Comment: Will I be able to add the code above to my page.tpl.php file?

Comment: Yes - not the cleanest solution but it would work. Don't forget to surround the code with PHP open and close tags <?php ?> to jump in and out of HTML.